# error while submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

this form is not submitting. It shows error message.

error:

> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
>   Reload this webpage.
>   Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
>   Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Form code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="newcss.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<?php if($_POST['submitForm'] == 'submit' ){
            echo "the Form has been submitted";
        } 
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="25" autofocus></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male">Male
                        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female"> Female
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><input type="email" name="Email" maxlength="35"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone Number:</td>
                    <td><input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" maxlength="20"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ask question and provide background information</td>
                    <td><textarea name="information" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="put your question and background information here"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="submit"><input type="reset" value="reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to get data in the form submitted so that once I'm able to confirm that data is submitted, I can work further with the webpage.

any suggestions?

Comment: I tested your code and it checks out. What is the question and are you getting any errors? And, are you sure your file has the `.php` extension?

Comment: when I try to submit the form there is an error message that no data was sent. it has a .html extension

Comment: I find that rather hard to believe. Are you running this off your own computer `localhost` or on a hosted website? AND does it have the `.php` file extension?

Comment: Your file MUST be `.php` and not `.html`

Comment: Have you tried testing other php code? Your server isn't likely to be set up to run php code on a page with HTML extension if you haven't explicitly configured it to do so. Do you see the php tags in the form when you load it at first?

Comment: Is PHP installed, or are you thinking that it will run just like a regular webpage?

Comment: Change the extension to .php, I've tested that exact code and it works fine

Comment: @JAL : there are no php tags when it runs

Comment: @fred I guess php is not installed because when I try to run it as .php the whole code is being displayed. Ill try to install it

Comment: `.html` runs off your "web browser", while `.php` runs off a "web **server**". If you don't have one installed, running and properly configured, then your code won't work by itself.

Comment: I guess I mean, when you View Source you should see the php when it's a html page. That would indicate it's not being processed. Probably it would be not visible in rendered content as the whole <?php etc?> is like a malformed HTML tag. But anyway, so it sounds like you determined php isn't installed/configured.

Answer (score 2):

Try supplying an action for the form. `action="filename.php"`

Also, instead of `if($_POST['submitForm'] == 'submit')`, use `if(isset($_POST['submitForm']))`. It'll prevent an `E_NOTICE` error from showing

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't work.. also the page is named .html would it make a difference?

Comment: If you're posting data using `$_POST`, then the file needs to be .php (unless your server is set to run .html as .php (.htaccess trick)

Answer (score 0):

In your php, just do :

`<?php
echo $_POST['submitForm'];
?>`

... you might be surprised by the result.

Comment: Which essentially means that nothing in your code is even evaluated. So you should read the answers above following your comment about the file extension, and look in that direction.

Comment: its solved.. I never activated php on my mac.. now its working

Comment: Definitely surprised by the results, since the results were "oh, you HAVENT EVEN INSTALLED PHP".

Comment: I am speechless. And this is a rare occurrence.